# How do I set the Windows system clock to the correct local time using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-xp, clock

How do I set the Windows system clock to the correct local time using C#?

Comment: how do you get the "right local time"?

Comment: What do you mean with "right local time"? Please explain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to P/Invoke the [`SetLocalTime` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724936.aspx) from the Windows API. Declare it like this in C#:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool SetLocalTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SYSTEMTIME
{
    public ushort wYear;
    public ushort wMonth;
    public ushort wDayOfWeek;    // ignored for the SetLocalTime function
    public ushort wDay;
    public ushort wHour;
    public ushort wMinute;
    public ushort wSecond;
    public ushort wMilliseconds;
}
```

To set the time, you simply initialize an instance of the `SYSTEMTIME` structure with the appropriate values, and call the function. Sample code:

```
SYSTEMTIME time = new SYSTEMTIME();
time.wDay = 1;
time.wMonth = 5;
time.wYear = 2011;
time.wHour = 12;
time.wMinute = 15;

if (!SetLocalTime(ref time))
{
    // The native function call failed, so throw an exception
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

However, note that the calling process must have the appropriate privileges in order to call this function. In Windows Vista and later, this means you will have to request process elevation.

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`SetSystemTime` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724942.aspx), which allows you to set the time in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). The same `SYSTEMTIME` structure is used, and the two functions are called in an identical fashion.

Answer (score 6):

.NET does not expose a function for that but you can use Win32 API [SetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (in kernel32.dll) method. To get UTC time you should use an [NTP Protocol Client](http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/c-simple-network-time-ntp-protocol-client-SID571.aspx) and then adjust that time to the local time according to your regional settings.

```
public struct SYSTEMTIME
{    
  public ushort wYear,wMonth,wDayOfWeek,wDay,wHour,wMinute,wSecond,wMilliseconds;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

SYSTEMTIME systime = new SYSTEMTIME();
systime = ... // Set the UTC time here
SetSystemTime(ref systime);
```

Comment: Wrong. This is for the Compact Framework, under Windows Mobile. The question is tagged "windows-xp".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of articles on how to do that, complete with querying an atomic clock for the correct time.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ntpclient.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/SNTPClient.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To get around the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege issue, try creating a scheduled task to run your application and enable "Run with highest privileges."