# Calling a datetime function from Web Service C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I have a GetLocalTime() method in my Web Service which I want to call in my form.cs and set the time on web server on the device on button click? So what should I write on the button click event to call the datetime function and set the time?

Method in Web Service:

```
[WebMethod]
        public DateTime GetLocalTime()
        {
            OracleBridge ob = new OracleBridge(_connStr);
            string sqlQuery = "select sysdate from dual";

            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            try
            {

                dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ob.ExecuteScalar(sqlQuery));

            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

Button click event in form.cs to get and set the time:

```
 private void btnSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                           ????????????               // what should I write here to call the method
                DateTime localDateTime = ?????????;  //what should I write here pass datetime to setsystemdatetime


                SetSystemDateTime(localDateTime);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                SetSystemDateTime(localDateTime); 
}
```

Comment: You'd get some code to make an HTTP POST to whatever your webmethod is. I don't know what the file is called where your webmethod is stored, but you'd post to a url such as... `http://server:port/file_with_webmethod.aspx/GetLocalTime` and that should return your DateTime. Maybe look up the `WebRequest` class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET CLR does not expose any method for setting the time.  If you are hell bent on doing this, you will need to work with the [Win32 SetLocalTime API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724936.aspx) and [import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083200/how-do-i-set-the-windows-system-clock-to-the-correct-local-time-using-c).

I advise against allowing a web server process to set the system clock.  When you are able to set the clock, you can cause all sorts of security mechanisms to be bypassed; for example, a malicious user can cause sessions or certificates that are otherwise expired to appear valid.

Comment: I am able to set the time on the device when I hardcode the time and now I just want to pass the value of the datetime function defined in GetLocalTime()  to the setlocaltime method. And security is not the issue on the project I am working on.